# read value from text file, Forward email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

i have the following code which is meant to forward an email, and include my own message.

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
Dim filenum As Integer
Dim current_number As String

filenum = FreeFile()
Open "G:\Infrastructure Services\Engineering Services\Hazard Report Number.txt" For Input As #filenum
While Not EOF(filenum)
Line Input #filenum, current_number

Wend


If item.Class = olMail Then
    If Left$(item.Subject, 29) = "Hazard Identification Report" Then
        Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim NewForward As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

        Set Msg = item
        Set NewForward = Msg.Forward
        Set olApp = Outlook.Application
        Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        strSender = ""
strsenderName = Msg.SenderEmailAddress





If strsenderName = "EX" Then
  Set objSender = itm.Sender
  If Not (objSender Is Nothing) Then
    Set objExchUser = Sender.GetExchangeUser()
    If Not (objExchUser Is Nothing) Then
      strSender = objExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    End If
  End If
Else
  strSender = strsenderName
End If



        With NewForward
            .Subject = "Hazard report reciept number:"
            .To = strSender
            .HTMLBody = "TYhank you for your email"
            .Send
        End With
        End If
    End If

ExitProc:
    Set NewForward = Nothing
    Set Msg = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing


End Sub
```

I've read the value in from my text file, no problem. the question i have is how do i delete the value from the text file, and print the value +1 back into the text file?

also, this is meant to forward the message back to the sender, including their original attachments and message (a photo and some GPS co-ordinates), but its not for some reason and i can't see why.

does any body have any suggestions?

Comment: You should really create two different questions for this. In answer to your first problem, you actually need create a new text file with all the data you want in it. The only way to edit a text file without doing this is to use ADO and I'm not even perfectly sure you can do it with that. I do know that ADO can only be used to access structured text files such as XML or CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite understand what your second problem is ("but ist not for some reason and I can't see why" is not the perfect error description).

But for replacing a txt-file with a new value use this:

```
 Call textfile_replace(Value + 1)
```

and this is the code you need:

```
Sub textfile_replace(mytext As String)
  On Error GoTo Fehler
  Dim Datei As String
  Dim Fnr As Long

    Datei = "c:\mytest.txt"
    Fnr = FreeFile
    Open Datei For Output As Fnr
Print #Fnr, mytext
    Close Fnr
    Exit Sub

Fehler:
    MsgBox "error" & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

If you send some more Information what problem you have with sending the mail I will try to help you there as well.

Max

Comment: I'm currently getting an Error55-file already open error pop up - any suggestions where this is from?

Comment: In which line does the error come? Does it also come straight after restart of Outlook / the PC, or only after second run? Are you sure no other programm is blocking the file?

Comment: I am getting the error after i have received the email in my inbox. it also appears to send out 2 or 3 reply emails via the macro.

Comment: Edit your questio above so we have the vode you are actually using. When the error message pops up, go to debugging and see which line is highlighted.