# Generate automatic ids

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have to do the following:

Open mail -> Check Subject -> If subject is not like : ..... cID#[4digit]   -> Add a cID#[4digit] to it, based on other mail's subjects in your folders and sub-folders -> other operations.

Basically check for the highest value of cID#, increment it by 1, and add it to the new subject. For example if your subject is: H&H 2013 allocation.

-It checks if the subject contains the cID# part.**✓**

-It can't find it, so it checks the folders, and sub-folders for the highest cID#; increment it by 1. **✗**

Getting the ID of a single mail as integer is done, because it is just the Val(Right(subjectstring.4)) (It will always be on the right, which is easier for me, because I couldn't find other methods, but they are more than welcome) From these values, it is easy to build the 4 length long string, and insert it to the subject.

My question is, how to get the highest valued cID#-s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading all existing e-mails will use some time and resources.

I would keep a text file on the hard-disk, in which you only store the highest value; when reading it and adding +1 for the next mail, also put the new number into your text file.

How-to: see my answer here: [read value from text file, Forward email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991325/read-value-from-text-file-forward-email/20011805?noredirect=1#comment29921259_20011805)

Max

Comment: It seems nice, I will try it tomorrow (14h from now, I will respond if it works :) )

Comment: Well this was good enough :)
But I couldn't make your method work, so I made it another way, I will edit it tomorrow in my post, if everyone else have the same problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Following Max's advice, my code is based on this, if anyone else has the same problem.
I use the szamid's to set the numbers.

```
Sub readtextfile()

Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim oFS As TextStream
Dim oFSBU As TextStream
Dim filePath As String
Dim filePathBU As String
Dim szamid As Integer
Dim My_filenumber As Integer

filePath = "C:\Casenumber.txt"
filePathBU = "C:\CasenumberBU.txt"
If Not fileExist(filePath) Then GoTo FileDoesntExist

On Error GoTo Err


Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading)
szamid = oFS.Read(7)
szamid = szamid + 1
szamid = CStr(szamid)
oFS.Close

Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForWriting)
oFS.WriteLine (szamid)
oFS.Close
Set oFSBU = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePathBU, ForWriting)
oFSBU.WriteLine (szamid)
oFSBU.Close

MsgBox szamid

Exit Sub

FileDoesntExist:

Set oFSBU = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePathBU, ForReading)
szamid = oFSBU.Read(7)
szamid = szamid + 1
szamid = CStr(szamid)
oFSBU.Close

Const FILENAME = "C:\Casenumber.txt"
My_filenumber = FreeFile
Open FILENAME For Output As #My_filenumber
Close #My_filenumber

Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForWriting)
oFS.WriteLine (szamid)
oFS.Close
Set oFSBU = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePathBU, ForWriting)
oFSBU.WriteLine (szamid)
oFSBU.Close
MsgBox szamid

Exit Sub

Err:
MsgBox "Error while reading the file.", vbCritical, vbNullString
oFS.Close
Exit Sub

End Sub
```